# How to restrict image to transform ( moving, scale ) to alway cover entire clipping path inside it?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a Image with a simple clipping Rect ( rotate 30 degree with size 200x200 to make a small view part of image ).
My problem is How to restrict image to transform to alway cover entire clipping path inside it ?

Here is my expected results:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVpJW.png)
Here is some demo right / wrong cases:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXgLA.jpg)
and I use fabric.js

```
// create a clipping path
var rectClippingPath = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 200,
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  fill: 'red',
  angle: 30,
  absolutePositioned: true
});

// create image
var newImage = new fabric.Image();
newImage.clipPath = rectClippingPath;
canvas.add(newImage);

newImage.setSrc('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', (imageObject) => {
  newImage.set({ left: 50, top: 50});
  canvas.setActiveObject(newImage);
  newImage.setCoords();
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
})
```

Comment: the question is from https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6585 ..but the origin question doesn't solve..